# regex php - find things in div with specific ID

Tags: php, regex, html, extract

I'm sure this is an easy one, and as much as I've googled and searched here on SO - I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this.  I have other areas on this page where I use similar expressions that return exactly what I want.

However, I can't get this particular bit to return what I want, so maybe someone can help me.

I have a div with a specific ID "user-sub-commhome" - I want to pull out the text from within that div.  The text is surrounded by  tags but I can easily use strip_tags to get those gone.  I'm using regex to try and pull the data out.

Here is my code:

```
$intro = "<div id="user-sub-summary">Summary</div>
<div id="user-sub-commhome"><em>Commercial</em></div>
<div id="whatever">whatever</div>";

$regex = '#\<div id="user-sub-commhome"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $intro, $matches);
$match = $matches[0];
echo $match;
```

I've tried changing things with no success, nothing seems to work to echo anything.  So I'm hoping some power that be who is much more experienced with regex can help.

Comment: Not sure if this is just sample code, but your $intro variable is not correct, since it's not properly being escaped.

Comment: I would suggest that you try using a html parser instead of regex for this task. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/159388.

Comment: Yes, this is just sample code.  $intro is actually a big chunk of html - I was just giving those as an example so people could see what I was talking about a bit more clear.

Comment: Your pattern works fine with the HTML not taking in account syntax errors in PHP noticed by Devator. Escape double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me if you change the enclosing doublequotes around `$intro` to single quotes:

```
$intro = '<div id="user-sub-summary">Summary</div>
<div id="user-sub-commhome"><em>Commercial</em></div>
<div id="whatever">whatever</div>';

$regex = '#\<div id="user-sub-commhome"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $intro, $matches);
$match = $matches[0];
echo $match;
```

You might want to read [some famous advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on regular expressions and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

i won't explain why [using regular expressions to parse php is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). i think the problem here is you don't have error_reporting activated or you're simply not looking into your error-log. defining the `$intro`-string the way you do should cause a lot of problems (unexpectet whatever / unterminatet string). it should look like this:

```
$intro = "<div id=\"user-sub-summary\">Summary</div>
<div id=\"user-sub-commhome\"><em>Commercial</em></div>
<div id=\"whatever\">whatever</div>";
```

or this:

```
$intro = '<div id="user-sub-summary">Summary</div>
<div id="user-sub-commhome"><em>Commercial</em></div>
<div id="whatever">whatever</div>';
```

if you're using double quotes inside a double-quotet string, you have to mask them using a backslash (`\`). anoter way would be to use single-quotes for the string (like in my second example).

Comment: Thanks - I should've clarified in the original one that the block of HTML was just for example purposes...
My code actually looks like this:
$intro = $form->data['introtext'];
That just brings in a big block of HTML - I have other regex expressions that are written virtually the same way (except they say "user-sub-summary" or whatever ID I'm trying to grab) and they all work.  Was just trying to see if anyone could find fault with this one...

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code `$matches[0]` contains all matched part, not the capturing group. The capturing group is in `$matches[1]`