# Fetching Data From A Specific div id Using PHP

Tags: php, html, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [read XML tag id from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035310/read-xml-tag-id-from-php)

what is the way to fetch data from A Specific div id Using PHP. What i want to do is to fetch data from a div id called `<div id="content">` , so all the data from that div id will be fetched in a variable.
I can fetch all content with my script but cant filter it to fetch data from a Specific div tag.
Here is the script i am using to fetch any content:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.example.com");
//parsing all content:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo "$html";
```

any idea?

Comment: you dont need curl to fetch the content. there is `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`. You can fetch an element by ID either via `getElementById()` or via XPath `//element[@id="name"]`. This has been asked and answered multiple times before and should be easy to find. When we ask you to do research in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice we really mean it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this but make sure you have downloaded and included [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com");
$displaybody = $html->find('div[id=content]', 0)->plaintext;
```

Their are some ways to exclude content from div id or Tag id like,

1) [Using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079861/regex-php-find-things-in-div-with-specific-id)

2) [Using SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

3) With [DOM extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) Or [XPath](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Comment: thanks Vinay its works like a magic! one more question is there any way to exclude content from a div id.. thanks

Comment: @user1642787 I have updated answer with some of way I know to exclude content from a div id.

Comment: thanks, i have tried with this but dont works `$regex = '#\<div class="sb_meta"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $displaybody, $matches);
$match = $matches[0];
echo $match;` any idea?

Comment: Read documentation I have posted, and then try, Now use this, $regex = '#\<div id="content"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s'; preg_match($regex, $html, $matches); $match = $matches[0]; echo $match;

Comment: i am sorry that was a div class i wanna exclude , it is that div class `<div class="sb_meta">` i have read all your documentation ..applied.. but not have the result .. any idea?

Comment: replace $displaybody with $html from your second comment. and try.

Comment: i have updated this script so it is now $displaybody

Answer (score 0):

With Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.example.com");

$html = file_get_html($content );
$ret = $html->find('div[id=divname]');
?>
```